# How to process object failed to satisfy the filter in java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to process object which is failed to satisfy the filter condition in the stream.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,23,43,12,4,5);
list.stream().filter( i -> i > 10).collect(Collections.toList);
```

This will return a list of Object greater than 10. but I also want to process the objects which are unable to satisfy the condition (>10).

Thank You.

Comment: Are you asking how to partition your list into two, based on a function that checks each value and either returns a truthy or falsey value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map = list.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i > 10));


map.get(false/true).... do whatever you want with those that failed or not
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just run two sweeps with `stream()` to get two different lists:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,23,43,12,4,5);

List<Integer> largerThanTen = list.stream().filter( i -> i > 10)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> smallerOrEqualToTen = list.stream().filter( i -> i <= 10)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think this is more readable than trying to do it in a one-liner, resulting in a less-idiomatic data structure.

Comment: I see no problem with this too, if you don't want to trade space for the `Map`... +1

Comment: @Eugene well, the map returned by `partitioningBy` is a really cheap custom implementation. Still, it’s hard to predict the performance differences between these two approaches in a world with JIT, hotspot optimizer, and CPU caches…

Comment: @Holger well, I only looked at the implementation *now* :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,23,43,12,4,5);
list.stream().filter( i -> i > 10).collect(Collections.toList);
```

> change to

```
Map < Boolean, List < Integer > > map = Stream.of( 1, 23, 43, 12, 4, 5 ).collect( Collectors.groupingBy( e -> e > 10 ) );
```

*then you can use*:

```
map.get( false )// is list of has not condition
map.get(true) // is list of has condition
```